# Duplicate code - Very similar UI but some of the components and methods are different - Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, duplicates, refactoring, code-duplication

I have a form where they have a similar UI to one another.
One is for creating and one is for editing. But some of the methods are the different.

What the best way to refactor this?

I was thinking of having a more generic component that has both the different methods in one file. But is there another other way that is better?

I can't really make this into a parent and child component because since they are too similar, and mostly differ in a few methods and some of the text labels/values?

Or would I add if else statements everywhere where the code is different?

Thank you!

Comment: It depends. Please, don't describe your code but post it. Preferably a simplified version of it that reflects the differences, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Create a reusable component that consists of the Template and styles. Then use it on other components.

Supposed.

*ReusableComponent.vue*

```js
    <template>
       <div> This is a Reusable component </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      export default {};
    </script>
    
    <style>
      ...
    </style>
```

*ComponentA.vue*

```js
    <template>
       <ReusableComponent />
    </template>
    
    <script>
      import ReusableComponent from './ReusableComponent';
    
      export default {
        components: {
          ReusableComponent,
        },
        methods: {
           methodJustforComponentA() {
             ...
           },
           ...
        }
      };
    </script>
```

*ComponentB.vue*

```js
    <template>
       <ReusableComponent />
    </template>
    
    <script>
      import ReusableComponent from './ReusableComponent';
    
      export default {
        components: {
          ReusableComponent,
        },
        methods: {
           anotherMethodJustforComponentB() {
             ...
           },
           someOtherMethods() {
             ...
           },
           ...
        }
      };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typical Create and Update in Vue/React is handled as follows. It is based on the assumption that your UI remains same during create and update workflows. What changes is the API and Authorization logic.

#### Step 1

Create a dumb `MyForm` component which has only static form controls that. In terms of props the component would have following props:

```
// Value of some type T that you receive from parent component to render
// @input event raised by `MyForm` for any changes done by user to the form
value: T;
@input: (newValue: T) => void;
```

#### Step 2

Create two **higher order components**, `NewEntity` and `EditEntity`. These two components are responsible for making API calls and getting the data. Further these components would then pass this data as `prop` to `MyForm` component.

These components would also be the leaf components i.e. the components connected to the client-side router endpoints.

#### Step 3

If you have some common behavior (Not UI - already extracted into `MyForm`. It is about behaviors like computation, APIs for autocomplete, suggestions, etc.), then you can use Mixins or Extend components using classes to further extract out the common code. With Vue 3, prefer to use composition API over Mixins for this.